# gzip json files sent to the browser

Tags: php, jquery, json, gzip

I have a ton of data to send to the browser, maybe 100mb or so.  I've chunked them up into smaller files so I can simulate streaming.  Let's say I have 200 files of 500kb each.  I build an array of the 200 files in javascript, and then loop over that and make ajax calls for each.  It works fine.  Then I wanted to improve it, so I gziped everything on the server and they went down to about 20% of the original chunk size.  My ajax calls the following file:

```
fileserver.php?file=/temp/media_C46_20110719_113332_ori-0.js.gz
```

In fileserver.php, I have, very simply:

```
$filepath = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : '';

  if($filepath!=''){
   if(substr($filepath,-2,2)=='gz'){
    header("Content-Type: text/plain" );
    header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($filepath)) );
    header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
    readfile(filepath);
  }
  else{
    header("Location: ".$filepath );
  }
}
```

Again, this totally works.  The problem is that it takes forever!  Looking at my network tab in chrome, it's taking 15 seconds or so to get a 100kb chunk.  I can download that file directly in less than a second.  The php script above should take virtually no time to run.  I know the client (browser) needs to spend a bit of time to inflate the content, but it's got to be less than a second.  So what's taking 15 seconds!  Are there any other tools I can use to check this out?

I know I could set the header variables in apache, but I don't have access to that, and doing it in php is functionally equivalent, right? Are those the correct headers to set?

Comment: Why the detour through the PHP script in the first place? Would it not make much more sense to enable compression for .js files directly in the web server?

Comment: I mentioned that in my last paragraph, I don't have access to edit the web server.  It's functionally equivalent, right?

Comment: You also might try changing the Content-type to `application/x-gzip`

Comment: It's not really equivalent: a memory-hogging PHP process has to be started to serve the file.  (that shouldn't cause a 15-second delay though.) Still, it would be much much better to do this in Apache's config or (if possible) in a `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem.  The filesize() function wasn't getting the correct path, so It was printing as blank.  I fixed that to send the correct info and it works much much faster now.